# next/image is not seen properly except desktop with layout responsive, i want same size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
<Image src={APIImagePath} alt={t("common:tokens")} layout="fill" className={styles.img} />
```

Desktop view

[image]

tablet view

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Next js Image needed a container that renders the Image as per height, width, and layout.

For more details follow next js documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

When the layout is fill, the image will stretch both width and height to the dimensions of the parent element, provided the parent element is relative.

When the layout is responsive, the image will scale the dimensions down for smaller viewports and scale up for larger viewports.

Always do this:

CSS as per requirement:

```
.imgContainer{
height:200px;
width:200px;
}
<div className={styles.imgContainer} >
<Image src={APIImagePath} alt={t("common:tokens")} layout="fill" className={styles.img} />
</div>
```

Comment: No, its not working, i added devicesize in next.config.js file, now its working.